# TypeError: Component is not a function on adding forwardRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-forwardref

Hi I was trying to add forwardRef to a child component but getting the following on adding the forwardRef:
`TypeError: Component is not a function`

The component is defined as below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { forwardRef } from 'react';
import { TextInputFocusEventData } from 'react-native';
import { NativeSyntheticEvent, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Input, InputProps } from 'react-native-elements';
import { Metrics, Colors } from '../../theme';
import Icons from '../Icons';


const CustomTextInput2 = forwardRef<TextInput, ICustomtextnputProps>((props, ref) => {
    const { name, required } = props;

    return (
        <Input
            rightIcon={<Icons name="right" />}
            placeholder={name?.concat(required ? '*' : '')}
            inputContainerStyle={styles.inputContainer}
            inputStyle={styles.inputText}
            {...props}
        />
    )
});
....
```

Here is the StackTrace:

```
ExceptionsManager.js:180 TypeError: Component is not a function

This error is located at:
    in Unknown (at AddDetailsModal/index.tsx:67)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AddDetailsModal/index.tsx:66)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:217)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:278)
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (at CustomModal/index.tsx:71)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:217)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:278)
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (at TouchableOpacity.js:221)
    in TouchableOpacity (at TouchableOpacity.js:271)
    in Unknown (at CustomModal/index.tsx:70)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at KeyboardAvoidingView.js:220)
    in KeyboardAvoidingView (at CustomModal/index.tsx:69)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:107)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:134)
    in AppContainer (at Modal.js:228)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Modal.js:249)
    in VirtualizedListContextResetter (at Modal.js:247)
    in RCTModalHostView (at Modal.js:234)
    in Modal (at CustomModal/index.tsx:63)
```

is there anything I have to change to add a forwardRef to this component?

Comment: Show the full error stack. Check the props of `Input`

Comment: @slideshowp2 added the stack trace, also Input is imported from 'react-native-elements' package

Comment: You're going to need to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  I tried to run your code and [I'm not getting any error](https://snack.expo.dev/PdPxXBMIl).  So the error is in something that you haven't included in your question.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

after wrap the component by React.forwardRef and pass ref from parent component you need to reload the app !
i faced that now and saw the same error message  and simply solved by reloading the app

Comment: i end up coming back to this comment everytime fml

Comment: I'd laugh and didn't act but since it's react, I tried and 20mins of struggle ended, thx